# Eagle routing gate swap and abitrary connectible pins

Tags: eaglecad, autorouter

Is it possible to have the Eagle autorouter swap gates or pins on parts allowing such exchanges to untangle traces ?

Comment: Yes, as is clearly described in the documentation.

Comment: I do not find that, maybe you misunderstood the question like Tom Carpenter?

Comment: Once again, the answer to your question is "Yes". And, I just checked, and it is both clearly documented and works as documented.  Do HELP PINSWAP.

Comment: Care to say *where* you found the information? The only information I can find that has pinswap and the autorouter together is a forum post from 2006 which says that the autorouter can't swap the pins automatically. Now a lot will have changed in 9 years, it would useful for everyone to know where you found the info.

Comment: "The PINSWAP command is used to swap pins within the same symbol which have been allocated the same swaplevel (> 0). Swaplevel, see PIN command. If a board is tied to a schematic via Back Annotation two pads can only be swapped if the related pins are swappable. 
On a board without a schematic this command permits two pads in the same package to be swapped. The Swaplevel is not checked in this case. 
Wires attached to the swapped pins are moved with the pins so that short circuits may appear. Please perform the DRC and correct possible errors. "

Where does it mention the autorouter?

Comment: I change 'router' to 'autorouter' in the text to clarify this a little. However, it was already tagged 'autorouter'.

Comment: It's possible, but Eagle's implementation is (as most things, sadly), lacking. You can set the swaplevel of any pins that you'd like to be able to swap to the same nonzero number and Eagle will let you swap them. with the pinswap command. Same idea as gateswap.  The ugly part is that when you do pinswap, eagle makes a hideous mess of your schematic.  EDIT: like others, I've misread. No, the autorouter can't do this for you.

Comment: @Tom: PINSWAP is available when manually routing, which is what the question was about.  I now see that this was changed only 21 minutes ago to ask about the auto-router being able to swap pins.  Argh! That of course totally changes the question.

Comment: Your latest edit of 21 minutes ago totally changes the question from what it was for a couple of days.  Thanks for wasting our time.  I'm outta here.  Find someone else to jerk around.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - I read it as meaning manual routing when I first answered the question, but actually when I re-read it, it was correctly tagged with 'autorouter', hence the edit to my answer a couple of days ago.

Comment: @Tom: You can't expect people to use the tags to get important information about the question.  I personally don't even look at them.  In any case, when there is a conflict between the question text and a tag, I'd go with the text as being more definative.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible for manual routing, but **cannot be automated**.

The autorouter does not have the capability to change your design - if it did, it would be quite a dangerous feature if for example you have a symbol with pinswap enabled but you didn't want those pins swapping (e.g. MCU or FPGA io pins with special purposes).

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to try autorouting then look at the results, if you see that the routing would be simpler with pins swapped then rip up the traces around the affected pins, manually swap the pins and then either run the autorouter again to finish things off or route those traces manually.

---

**For manual changes:**

If you have groups of pins (e.g. on I/O pins on a uC, or the inputs of a logic gate) that are able to be swapped, then what you do is edit your library component to tell the schematic symbol which pins can be swapped with which.

In the library editor, open your symbol. If you go to the properties of any of the pins in that symbol, you will see a setting called 'Swap Level'. A non-zero value means that any pin with that value can be swapped with another pin with the same non-zero value. E.g. an AND gate with two inputs could have both inputs set to have a swap-level of 1, allowing both to be switched. If you have multiple groups of pins, just set each group to a different swap level.

Once you have set your swap levels, saved, and updated the library in your schematic. You can then swap the pins as you please.
You will see a button which shows an AND gate with an arrow pointing to both inputs, which when you hover over it is titled 'Pinswap'. Alternatively you can type pinswap into the command bar to enable the tool. Simply click on the first pin you want to swap, and then the second. If both pins you select have the same swap level, the two connections will be reversed for you in the schematic.

Once you have swapped the pins, you may find you have to tidy up the schematic/layout as the wires/traces directly connected to the pins will be moved so they connect to the new pin.

Comment: Ok, so the answer would be 'it is not possible' I guess. Thanks!